# Removing inputs leads to incorrect values

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Ok, so the problem is pretty simple, but hard to explain.

I'm making an InputGenerator component, which generates a list of inputs.

Each generated input has a corresponding "remove" button next to it. The two elements (the input and the button) are wrapped in a div inside a map function. The div has a unique key prop. It looks like this (this is the whole component's jsx):

```
        <div style={[InputGenerator.style.wrapper]}>
            <div className="container" style={InputGenerator.style.container}>
                {this.state.inputs.map((input, idx) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={idx} style={[
                            InputGenerator.style.row,
                            InputGenerator.count > 1 && idx > 0 ? InputGenerator.style.input.pushTop : {},
                        ]}>
                            <InputText
                                id={input.id}
                                name={input.name}
                                placeholder={input.placeholder}
                                style={input.style}
                            />
                            <Button
                                style={InputGenerator.style.remove}
                                type={Button.TYPES.BASIC}
                                icon="ion-close-round"
                                onClick={this.remove.bind(this, input.id)}
                            />
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>

            <div className="controls" style={InputGenerator.style.controls}>
                <Button icon="ion-plus" type={Button.TYPES.PRIMARY} title="Add ingredient" onClick={this.add.bind(this)}/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

As you may see, all the inputs are kept in the this.state object and each one is given an unique id.

Here are the are add and remove methods:

add():

```
add() {
    InputGenerator.count++;

    const newInput = {
        id: this.id,
        name: this.props.name,
        placeholder: this.props.placeholder,
        style: this.style,
        value: '',
    };

    const inputs = this.state.inputs;

    inputs.push(newInput);

    this.setState({ inputs });
}
```

remove():

```
remove(id) {
    this.setState({
        inputs: this.state.inputs.filter(i => i.id !== id),
    });
}
```

The problem is:

- I generate three inputs (using the add button)
- I put random values in the inputs (e.g: 1, 2, 3)
- I click on the remove button, corresponding to the first element (with value 1)
- Result: Two input items with values 1 and 2
- Expected: Two input items with values 2 and 3
- The problem: I suggest that the key prop on the wrapping div is not enough for react to keep track of the input's values.

So, I'm open for ideas and suggestions how to proceed.

Here's an isolated sandbox to play around with my component and see the "bug" in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/5985AKxRB

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you facing is because you are not handling state properly. You need to update state when you change input value.

```
  handleChange(index,event) {
    let inputs = this.state.inputs;
    inputs[index].value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({inputs:inputs})
  }
```

DEMO : [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/Q02x3rKAZ)

Here is the updated code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';
    import Hello from './Hello';

    const styles = {
      fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
      textAlign: 'center',
    };

    const App = () =>
      <div style={styles}>
        <InputGenerator />
      </div>;

    class InputGenerator extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          inputs: [],
        };
      }
      componentWillMount() {
        this.add();
      }
      handleChange(index,event) {
        let inputs = this.state.inputs;
        inputs[index].value = event.target.value;
        this.setState({inputs:inputs})
      }
      add() {
        InputGenerator.count++;

        const newInput = {
          id: this.id,
          name: this.props.name,
          placeholder: this.props.placeholder,
          style: this.style,
          value: '',
        };

        const inputs = this.state.inputs;

        inputs.push(newInput);

        this.setState({ inputs });
      }
      get id() {
        if (this.props.id) {
          return `${this.props.id}-${InputGenerator.count}`;
        }

        return `InputGeneratorItem-${InputGenerator.count}`;
      }
      get style() {
        return [];
      }
      remove(id) {

        var state = this.state;
        state.inputs = state.inputs.filter(i => i.id !== id);
        this.setState({
          inputs: state.inputs
        });
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <div className="container">
              {this.state.inputs.map((input, idx) => {
                return (
                  <div key={idx}>
                    <input
                      id={input.id}
                      name={input.name}
                      value = {input.value}
                      onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this,idx)}
                      placeholder={input.placeholder}
                    />
                    <button onClick={this.remove.bind(this, input.id)}>
                      Remove
                    </button>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>

            <div className="controls">
              <button onClick={this.add.bind(this)}>Add</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    InputGenerator.count = 0;

    render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thank you, Ved, that's exactly the way to do it. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Welcome.!! Happy to help.